# Algorithm to arrange audio tracks on a number of sides of vinyl, optimizing for smallest maximum side length?

Tags: recursion, optimization, linear-programming

We have a number of audio tracks, and a number of groups called “sides” (each corresponding to one side of a vinyl record). For each track, we know its **name** and its **length** in seconds. Each side also has a length, which is the sum of the lengths of the tracks on the side. Typically one side will be longer than all the others. This the **maximum side length**, and it varies depending on how we arrange the tracks. What arrangement of the tracks results in the SMALLEST maximum side length? The problem reduces to [Multiway number partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_number_partitioning).

User @erwin-kalvelagen proposed using a MIP solver (CPLEX). However his GAMS code generates the input song lengths randomly, whereas I need to input specific song lengths. Also, his code outputs the computed side lengths, but not which song goes on which side. I managed to adapt his code to solve both of these problems. The corrected code is below, along with its NEOS output.

```
set
   i 'songs' /song1*song23/
   j 'sides' /side1*side8/
;

parameter len(i) 'length of song in seconds' / 
song1 323,
song2 289,
song3 329,
song4 424,
song5 351,
song6 369,
song7 298,
song8 296,
song9 358,
song10 358,
song11 342,
song12 275,
song13 300,
song14 280,
song15 283,
song16 348,
song17 347,
song18 357,
song19 243,
song20 244,
song21 255,
song22 308,
song23 360
/;

binary variable x(i,j) 'assignment';
variable z 'maximum length of side';

equations
   maximum(j) 'bound on z'
   assign(i)  'assignment constraints'
   ;
   
maximum(j).. z =g= sum(i, len(i)*x(i,j));
assign(i).. sum(j, x(i,j)) =e= 1;

model m /all/;
option threads=0, mip=cplex;
solve m minimizing z using mip;

parameter slen(j) 'solution: length of sides';
slen(j) = sum(i, len(i)*x.l(i,j));

option decimals = 0;
option x:0:0:1;
display len,slen,z.l,x.l;
```

Resulting output from CPLEX at [NEOS](https://neos-server.org/neos/solvers/lp:CPLEX/GAMS.html#webform) (abbreviated):

```
Proven optimal solution
MIP Solution:          936.000000    (160060 iterations, 15252 nodes)
Final Solve:           936.000000    (0 iterations)

Best possible:         936.000000
Absolute gap:           -0.000000
Relative gap:           -0.000000

[snip]

----     56 PARAMETER slen  solution: length of sides

side1 936,    side2 936,    side3 936,    side4 793,    side5 931,    side6 936
side7 933,    side8 936


----     56 VARIABLE z.L                   =          936  maximum length of si
                                                           de

----     56 VARIABLE x.L  assignment

song1 .side1 1
song2 .side3 1
song3 .side7 1
song4 .side4 1
song5 .side8 1
song6 .side4 1
song7 .side2 1
song8 .side6 1
song9 .side2 1
song10.side1 1
song11.side8 1
song12.side5 1
song13.side3 1
song14.side2 1
song15.side6 1
song16.side5 1
song17.side3 1
song18.side6 1
song19.side8 1
song20.side7 1
song21.side1 1
song22.side5 1
song23.side7 1
```

Comment: Did you exclude assignments that are equivalent (the distribution is the same in principle, just assigned to different "side names")? If so, how?

Comment: It looks like NP-complete so although there may be good heuristics, this should be exponential in the worst case. For <20 items, it should be Ok though. Do you have some large inputs in practice?

Comment: @jérôme-richard Yes I do have large inputs in practice. For example distributing 23 tracks on 8 sides of vinyl stalls my algorithm and I estimate it would take days or weeks to finish. But 16 tracks is OK.

Comment: @stefan-haustein I didn't, and it may well be contributing to the slowdown. So far I didn't find a method of eliminating those duplicates without involving database-like access methods. I already optimized my code so that all memory is allocated beforehand. Sorting the input beforehand also helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest is to develop a small MIP (Mixed-Integer Programming) model. This can be solved with readily available MIP solvers.

The very simple mathematical model can look like:

```
Indices:
    i : song
    j : side

Data:
    length[i] 

Decision variables:
   x[i,j]=1 if song i is assigned to side j
          0 otherwise
   z : maximum length
 

Optimization Model: 

minimize z
subject to the constraints:
    z >= sum(i, x[i,j]*length[i])     ∀j
    sum(j, x[i,j]) = 1                ∀i
    x[i,j] ∈ {0,1}
```

Of course, this must be transcribed into code to be fed to a solver. As the model is very simple, this is quite easy. The exact syntax depends on the chosen language, modeling tool and solver.

To give an idea about performance: a problem with n=200 songs (with random lengths) and m=10 sides took 9 seconds to solve to proven optimality (using a good MIP solver). I also see good performance with
Google's OR-Tools CP-Sat solver.

---

**Test data and results**

```
----     27 PARAMETER len  random data: length of song

song1   200.000,    song2   282.000,    song3   246.000,    song4   216.000,    song5   215.000,    song6   207.000
song7   222.000,    song8   283.000,    song9   188.000,    song10  240.000,    song11  300.000,    song12  250.000
song13  299.000,    song14  272.000,    song15  195.000,    song16  257.000,    song17  199.000,    song18  210.000
song19  260.000,    song20  232.000,    song21  223.000,    song22  222.000,    song23  195.000,    song24  198.000
song25  251.000,    song26  280.000,    song27  207.000,    song28  260.000,    song29  273.000,    song30  216.000
song31  193.000,    song32  240.000,    song33  199.000,    song34  285.000,    song35  212.000,    song36  214.000
song37  251.000,    song38  267.000,    song39  256.000,    song40  236.000,    song41  230.000,    song42  194.000
song43  218.000,    song44  185.000,    song45  220.000,    song46  202.000,    song47  258.000,    song48  247.000
song49  273.000,    song50  216.000,    song51  259.000,    song52  271.000,    song53  255.000,    song54  214.000
song55  190.000,    song56  192.000,    song57  257.000,    song58  245.000,    song59  183.000,    song60  275.000
song61  188.000,    song62  201.000,    song63  243.000,    song64  270.000,    song65  201.000,    song66  184.000
song67  250.000,    song68  255.000,    song69  227.000,    song70  223.000,    song71  209.000,    song72  209.000
song73  195.000,    song74  292.000,    song75  225.000,    song76  274.000,    song77  216.000,    song78  195.000
song79  270.000,    song80  188.000,    song81  204.000,    song82  180.000,    song83  212.000,    song84  240.000
song85  198.000,    song86  201.000,    song87  220.000,    song88  218.000,    song89  218.000,    song90  296.000
song91  300.000,    song92  224.000,    song93  225.000,    song94  273.000,    song95  227.000,    song96  290.000
song97  194.000,    song98  268.000,    song99  186.000,    song100 249.000,    song101 186.000,    song102 180.000
song103 228.000,    song104 242.000,    song105 256.000,    song106 207.000,    song107 227.000,    song108 213.000
song109 198.000,    song110 293.000,    song111 231.000,    song112 196.000,    song113 226.000,    song114 225.000
song115 212.000,    song116 294.000,    song117 202.000,    song118 215.000,    song119 189.000,    song120 228.000
song121 192.000,    song122 226.000,    song123 219.000,    song124 203.000,    song125 193.000,    song126 252.000
song127 241.000,    song128 185.000,    song129 274.000,    song130 294.000,    song131 252.000,    song132 253.000
song133 223.000,    song134 251.000,    song135 262.000,    song136 241.000,    song137 199.000,    song138 259.000
song139 243.000,    song140 195.000,    song141 299.000,    song142 207.000,    song143 261.000,    song144 273.000
song145 292.000,    song146 204.000,    song147 215.000,    song148 203.000,    song149 209.000,    song150 258.000
song151 268.000,    song152 190.000,    song153 198.000,    song154 232.000,    song155 202.000,    song156 263.000
song157 272.000,    song158 198.000,    song159 227.000,    song160 264.000,    song161 282.000,    song162 254.000
song163 298.000,    song164 183.000,    song165 202.000,    song166 190.000,    song167 245.000,    song168 195.000
song169 268.000,    song170 193.000,    song171 239.000,    song172 276.000,    song173 239.000,    song174 244.000
song175 181.000,    song176 245.000,    song177 234.000,    song178 298.000,    song179 202.000,    song180 199.000
song181 182.000,    song182 201.000,    song183 187.000,    song184 182.000,    song185 281.000,    song186 252.000
song187 183.000,    song188 203.000,    song189 295.000,    song190 220.000,    song191 251.000,    song192 211.000
song193 257.000,    song194 198.000,    song195 235.000,    song196 227.000,    song197 277.000,    song198 245.000
song199 227.000,    song200 247.000


----     27 PARAMETER slen  solution: length of sides

side1  4625.000,    side2  4624.000,    side3  4625.000,    side4  4624.000,    side5  4620.000,    side6  4625.000
side7  4624.000,    side8  4624.000,    side9  4625.000,    side10 4625.000


----     27 VARIABLE z.L                   =     4625.000  maximum length of side
```

This was solved with GAMS and Cplex (commercial). The implementation looks like:

```
set
   i 'songs' /song1*song200/
   j 'sides' /side1*side10/
;

parameter len(i) 'random data: length of song';
len(i) = uniformint(3*60,5*60);
option len:0;
display len;

binary variable x(i,j) 'assignment';
variable z 'maximum length of side';

equations
   maximum(j) 'bound on z'
   assign(i)  'assignment constraints'
   ;
   
maximum(j).. z =g= sum(i, len(i)*x(i,j));
assign(i).. sum(j, x(i,j)) =e= 1;

model m /all/;
option threads=0, mip=cplex;
solve m minimizing z using mip;

parameter slen(j) 'solution: length of sides';
slen(j) = sum(i, len(i)*x.l(i,j));
display len,slen,z.l;

abort$(sum(i,len(i))<>sum(j,slen(j))) "solution does not add up";
```

You can submit this model to https://neos-server.org/neos/index.html if you don't have access to these tools.

Here is another implementation using ORTools CP-Sat solver (open source). Again, I just transcribed the mathematical model, which is really a trivial task (both for GAMS and for OR-tools). For the CP model syntax see the guides here: https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp.

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

'''

Optimization Model
------------------

min z
    z >= sum(i, x[i,j]*length[i])     ∀j
    sum(j, x[i,j]) = 1                ∀i
    x[i,j] ∈ {0,1}

For CP model the assumptions are:
   All variables and all coefficients are integers 

Note: CP model has also max() function. Here we just use the MIP
formulation. 

Documentation on ORTools is here: https://developers.google.com/optimization

'''


lengths = [
 200,  282,  246,  216,  215,  207,  222,  283,  188,  240,  300,  250,  299,  272,  195,  257,
 199,  210,  260,  232,  223,  222,  195,  198,  251,  280,  207,  260,  273,  216,  193,  240,
 199,  285,  212,  214,  251,  267,  256,  236,  230,  194,  218,  185,  220,  202,  258,  247,
 273,  216,  259,  271,  255,  214,  190,  192,  257,  245,  183,  275,  188,  201,  243,  270,
 201,  184,  250,  255,  227,  223,  209,  209,  195,  292,  225,  274,  216,  195,  270,  188,
 204,  180,  212,  240,  198,  201,  220,  218,  218,  296,  300,  224,  225,  273,  227,  290,
 194,  268,  186,  249,  186,  180,  228,  242,  256,  207,  227,  213,  198,  293,  231,  196,
 226,  225,  212,  294,  202,  215,  189,  228,  192,  226,  219,  203,  193,  252,  241,  185,
 274,  294,  252,  253,  223,  251,  262,  241,  199,  259,  243,  195,  299,  207,  261,  273,
 292,  204,  215,  203,  209,  258,  268,  190,  198,  232,  202,  263,  272,  198,  227,  264,
 282,  254,  298,  183,  202,  190,  245,  195,  268,  193,  239,  276,  239,  244,  181,  245,
 234,  298,  202,  199,  182,  201,  187,  182,  281,  252,  183,  203,  295,  220,  251,  211,
 257,  198,  235,  227,  277,  245,  227,  247
]

N = len(lengths)  # number of songs
M = 10            # number of sides

I = range(N)      # songs  
J = range(M)      # sides

#
# Specify Optimization Model
# This is a direct transcription of the mathematical model.
#

model = cp_model.CpModel()
x = {(i,j):model.NewBoolVar(f'x[{i},{j}]') for i in I for j in J}
z = model.NewIntVar(0,sum(lengths),'z')

for j in J:
    model.Add(z >= sum([x[(i,j)]*lengths[i] for i in I]))

for i in I:
    model.Add(sum([x[(i,j)] for j in J]) == 1)

model.Minimize(z)

#
# Solve 
# for better performance on large instances use multiple worker threads
#

solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
status = solver.Solve(model)
print(f'Status: {solver.StatusName(status)}')
print(f'Objective value: {solver.ObjectiveValue()}')


#
# reporting
#

for j in J:
    print(f'side: {j}, length: {sum([solver.Value(x[(i,j)])*lengths[i] for i in I])}')
```

The results should be:

```
Status: OPTIMAL
Objective value: 4625.0
side: 0, length: 4625
side: 1, length: 4621
side: 2, length: 4624
side: 3, length: 4622
side: 4, length: 4625
side: 5, length: 4624
side: 6, length: 4625
side: 7, length: 4625
side: 8, length: 4625
side: 9, length: 4625
```

Are any improvements possible? I would experiment with some additional symmetry-breaking constraints. They can make a lot of difference in performance.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. Can you recommend a free / open-source MIP solver that would run in Windows 10 and accept your syntax? It appears to be a very crowded field, and it's unclear how optimal some of the many solvers are. There are a few cloud-based solvers (Google provides one for example). My goal is to produce an app that solves the problem in domain-specific terms, starting with a track list containing titles and track durations. It could be a native command-line app but it would probably be more useful as an online calculator, e.g. in Javascript with Python.

Comment: I sent your model to my mathematician friend (at Harvard Observatory) hoping he could plug them into R (which supposedly includes a MIP solver), and here is his reply: "The few lines of code in MIP he sent you is not enough information to solve the problem, nor is it in R language. Non trivial. I do not get how it can minimize sums that have not been calculated. Those sums are the result of a combinatorial problem that is large." He also directed me to this link: https://veeroute.com/combinatorial-and-linear-integer-optimization/

Comment: Indeed this is not R code. It is a mathematical model. It needs to be transcribed into the format the solver/modeling tool expects. For this simple model, that is rather trivial. Many mathematicians have some familiarity with mathematical optimization, but not all of them. The rest does not make much sense to ("minimize sums"? I minimize a scalar variable z here).  I solve (well-crafted) MIP models with thousands of variables.

Comment: Thank you for this interesting data. What does “to proven optimality” mean? Does that mean the solver has computed the most optimal solution? If so, do you know that? Also I would like to repeat your experiment myself. Which solver did you actually use for the above results? Is it one I could possibly gain access to? But even if it’s not available, please also post the code you fed to the solver, because this will help me understand how to translate your model into code for whatever solver I ultimately end up using.

Comment: PS: it seems that SCIP and lpsolve are both freely available. And they have a front end in GitHub (gnosis miplib). Could your model be easily adapted to either of these? I’m just trying to arrive at a place where I can solve the problem (which is not an exercise, but an actual real-world problem posed by a friend who runs a record label).

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand why you could not do the transcription of the model yourself. It is really just a trivial programming task that does not require much thought. Anyway, I posted some Python code.

Comment: Thank you for posting the Python code. I would not characterize this  task as trivial, unsurprisingly, as otherwise I wouldn’t have asked for help.

Comment: Proven optimality means that this is a solution with an objective value that cannot be improved upon, guaranteed. The solutions themselves are not unique, but you will not be able to find better solutions. Puting it differently, these are not heuristics that just provide "good" solutions.  Note: "most optimal" is not a proper phrase. There is no such thing.

Comment: IMHO just a fraction of the complexity of your code. Most of the Python code is data and comments.

Comment: Well of course your solution is less code, because all the complexity moves to the MIP solver. Also your code is far from being an end-user solution, as unlike mine it excludes CSV parsing, track titles, help and other essential user features. You’re good, thank you, but no need to gloat or overstate your case.

Answer (score 0):

Potential improvements I can think of (Updated):

- In order to eliminate redundant combinations, always select the longest title (still) available when "starting" a new side -- including the first. This ensures the following invariant: the longest title overall will always be on side A, the longest title that is not on A will be on B etc.
- Keep track of the "globally" best side length found so far and don't consider combinations where a side exceeds this length
- Keep track of the minimum side length implied by best solution so far and use it to prune the recursion
- Use a simple heuristic to decide whether to check a new side or more titles first

I thought "this should be straightforward and not require a MIP solver" -- but best I was able get was abotu 10 minutes for 23 titles on 8 sides (in Kotlin for my convenience but it should be easily portable to C -- perhaps it's a bit faster there):

```kotlin
class RecordDistributor(lengths: List<Int>, val sideCount: Int) {
  // Invariants
  private val lengths = lengths.sortedDescending().toIntArray()
  private val titleCount = lengths.size
  private val idealSideLength = lengths.sum() / sideCount
  private val expectedSideLength = idealSideLength * 8 / 10

  // State
  private val sides = IntArray(sideCount)
  private val ordered = IntArray(titleCount)
  private var used: Long = 0L
  private var currentSide = -1
  private var titleIndex = -1

  // Results
  var bestSides = listOf<Int>()
  var bestLengths = listOf<Int>()
  var best = Int.MAX_VALUE
  var minSideLength = 0

  private fun findFirstUnused(): Int {
    for (i in 0 until titleCount) {
      if ((used and (1L shl i)) == 0L) {
        return i
      }
    }
    throw RuntimeException("Illegal state")
  }

  fun checkBest() {
    val maxSide = sides.max()
    if (maxSide < best) {
      best = maxSide
      bestLengths = ordered.toList()
      bestSides = sides.toList()
      minSideLength = lengths.sum() - best * (sideCount - 1)

      println("Best so far: $best; minSideLength: $minSideLength")
    }
  }

  fun tryNewSide() {
    val index = findFirstUnused()
    used = used or (1L shl index)
    val length = lengths[index]
    sides[++currentSide] = length
    ordered[++titleIndex] = length

    // No more sides available, just fill in the remaining titles and check
    if (currentSide == SIDE_COUNT - 1) {
      val savedIndex = titleIndex
      for (i in 0 until titleCount) {
        if ((used and (1L shl i)) == 0L) {
          val len = lengths[i]
          sides[currentSide] += len
          ordered[++titleIndex] = len
        }
      }
      checkBest()
      titleIndex = savedIndex
    } else {
      tryAll(0)
    }

    titleIndex--
    sides[currentSide--] = 0
    used = used xor (1L shl index)
  }

  private fun tryAll(fromIndex: Int) {
    if (titleIndex == titleCount - 1) {
      checkBest()
    } else {
      val sideLength = sides[currentSide]
      val tryNewSideFirst = sideLength > expectedSideLength && sideLength > minSideLength
      if (tryNewSideFirst) {
        tryNewSide()
      }
      for (i in fromIndex until titleCount) {
        if ((used and (1L shl i)) == 0L) {
          used = used or (1L shl i)
          val len = lengths[i]
          val newSideLen = sideLength + len
          if (newSideLen < best) {
            sides[currentSide] = newSideLen
            ordered[++titleIndex] = len
            tryAll(i + 1)
            titleIndex--
          }
          used = used xor (1L shl i)
        }
      }
      sides[currentSide] = sideLength
      if (!tryNewSideFirst && sideLength > minSideLength) {
        tryNewSide()
      }
   }
  }
}

val SIDE_COUNT = 8
val RECORDS = """23 skidoo,5:38
400 blows,6:07
A Certain Ratio,3:15
African Headcharge,3:36
Allez Allez ,3:40
Animal Magic,3:49
Basement 5,5:14
Disconnection,5:15
EP4,4:42
Lifetones,6:43
Mark Stewart,3:43
Maximum Joy,7:53
PIL,7:35
Snakefinger,4:41
Startled Insects,5:35
The Unknown Case,5:51
Bonus track 17,3:17
Bonus track 18,4:18
Bonus track 19,5:19
Bonus track 20,6:20
Bonus track 21,7:21
Bonus track 22,3:22
Bonus track 23,4:23"""


fun main() {
  val lengths = RECORDS.split("\n").map {
    var len = it.split(",")[1].split(":")
    len[0].toInt() * 60 + len[1].toInt()
  }

  println(lengths)

  val distributor = RecordDistributor(lengths, SIDE_COUNT)

  val t0 = System.currentTimeMillis()
  distributor.tryNewSide()
  val time = (System.currentTimeMillis() - t0) / 1000.0

  println("best: ${distributor.best} sides: ${distributor.bestSides} lengths: ${distributor.bestLengths} time: $time")
}
```

Output:

best: 887 sides: [876, 886, 884, 878, 883, 884, 879, 887] lengths: [473, 403, 455, 229, 202, 441, 223, 220, 380, 282, 216, 367, 319, 197, 351, 338, 195, 335, 281, 263, 315, 314, 258] time: 650.146

Comment: I sort the tracks in decreasing order at the beginning, ensuring that the longest track is inserted first on any given side, as you suggest. The side length limit plays a role: the descending sort also ensures for an arrangement in which one or more sides exceed the limit, the offending sides will be encountered near the root of the tree, instead of near the leaves, thereby avoiding much needless recursion. And I keep track of the current "global winner" (with the smallest maximum side length encountered so far) and stop exploring any branch that produces a side length exceeding the winner.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting suggestions. You're right, adding the track titles at the end would allow me to work with integers only, which that might help performance a bit. I'm experimenting with this calculator https://planetcalc.com/9814/ right now, and for the same data set that causes my algorithm to take too long, it's also taking too long. So we're up against NP, and for input above a certain threshold, we can't try every case. I'm looking into introducing a time limit, so that the user can obtain a partial result after however long they're willing to wait.

Comment: Added some more constraints and actual kotlin code, but wasn't able to get better than 10 minutes runtime for 23 titles on 8 sides... :-/

Comment: This is very interesting and I will try it ASAP. I would prefer not involve a MIP solver as this makes it MUCH more difficult to provide a complete end-user solution. Of course it’s nice that Erwin’s code takes a few seconds but in practical terms, 23 tracks is the worst case I’m likely to encounter,  so it might be preferable to keep the app self-contained even if it sacrifices some speed.

Comment: Might make sense to play around with the strategy for some smaller sets where the performance can be measured relatively quickly....

Answer (score -1):

The problem is **NP-complete**. It is closely related to the [**bin-packing problem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). Here is a proof:

You have a set of N items (audio track) that you want to balance in M containers (sides) so to minimize the size of the container (length of a side). The bin-packing decision problem is basically: find if the N items can be packed optimally so that they fit in M containers of a given size. This decision problem is **NP-complete**. You can reduce your problem to this bin-packing one. Indeed, the size of the container (the same in your case) is bounded: you can easily find a lower-bound where all items are guaranteed not to fit in the M container whatever the assignment, and find an upper-bound so all items are guaranteed to fit in the M container. This can be done by sorting the duration of the items and computing the sum the K first/last items. The idea is then do a **binary search** so to find the minimal size of the container where all items can fit. The reduction can be done in `O(log(U-L) * T)` time where `U` is the upper-bound duration, `L` is the lower-bound duration and `T` is the complexity of solving the bin-packing instance.

Note that the reduction can also be applied in the reverse way: some instance of the bin-packing decision problems (the one where all containers are equal like above), known to be NP-complete, can be reduced in your problem. Indeed, one can compute the optimal container size and check if it is bigger than a given size.

Since the best algorithm to solve the bin-packing instance is exponential, the best algorithm known for your algorithm is exponential too (if you succeed to find a polynomial algorithm, then it means you have proven that [P=NP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem) or that the above proof is wrong). The logarithmic transformation is great since this factor should be often small in your case (typically 10-15) and it means you can find an algorithm that is close to the speed of the best bin-packing algorithm. The good news is that you can reuse the best known bin-packing algorithm from decades of research. Thus, while this strategy may not give you best possible implementation, it certainly give you a very good algorithm based on the state-of-the-art (likely better than an algorithm written from scratch). Note that the better the lower/upper bound, the faster the binary search, so it is a good idea to find a pretty good bound. One can use randomized methods to quickly find a relatively small bound.

Comment: It looks like others have considered this problem. For example: "This online calculator searches for the solution of the multiway number partitioning optimization problem using the Complete Greedy Algorithm. The multiway number partitioning is the problem of partitioning a multiset of numbers into a fixed number of subsets, such that the sums of the subsets are as similar as possible." https://planetcalc.com/9814/

Comment: Here is more information on Multiway Number Partitioning, which appears to fit my problem exactly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_number_partitioning

Comment: NP-completeness says (almost) nothing about how fast a particular instance can be solved. People still make money developing MIP solvers.